# Handling ranges where the unit prefixes the number

Tags: numbers, measuring-units, money

If the unit follows the number, then according to the accepted answer of the [Including units of a measure in a range](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/110402/including-units-of-a-measure-in-a-range) , you can skip the unit for the first value, such as "1–5 ℥".

However, that question, and the section of the source cited in the accepted answer, doesn't describe what should happen if the unit prefixes the number. Should it be

> Jeans cost $10-100

or

> Jeans cost 10-$100

or is only

> Jeans cost $10-$100.

acceptable?

Comment: Is there a hat for that?

Comment: @oerkelens I get to wear a pair of jeans on my head.